# Where can I get the data base for Masoret Hashas?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, technology

I really interested about the connections between *masechtot*, I mean like how many times does *Masechet Brachot* quote *Masechet Shabat* for example.

So, for this I need all the data of the *Masoret Hashas*, does anyone know where I can get it?

Comment: What format do you want it in?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider registering your account which allows you to utilize various additional features of the site.

Comment: how many times does masechet berachot quote masechet Shabbat. If you ask for mishnayot or toseftot, ok, but a statement of an amora for instance, is not the property of masechet berachot than Shabbat. The statement was free and is linked to both.

Comment: I suggest you try searching on [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/). I'm not sure if that site can answer your specific question: if not, I suggest you contact the maintainers as they might be able to help. (Credit to @doubleAA for mentioning Sefaria in a comment.)

Comment: I know I'm late to the game, but check out https://www.sefaria.org/explore
Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, I'm unable to access it currently, but if I remember correctly it graphs all the connections between Masechtot in Shas.

Comment: [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301847848_Identification_of_Parallel_Passages_Across_a_Large_HebrewAramaic_Corpus) explains the algorithms needed to create a mesorat hashas. It also includes a link to download a compiled executable you can use to generate a new one.

Answer (score 2):

BSD

Try using Sefaria Connections. They have a lot of connections under the "Masores HaShas" label. Try there, despite the fact that they may not have everything.